# Translation of “taken as a whole” in this context?

Tags: translation, phrase

I would like to use the phrase *taken as a whole* in a piece. However, I am unsure as to what sounds the most natural in this context.

> London, taken as a whole, is fantastic.

Should I use *im Ganzen, insgesamt,* or something else entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> London im Gesamten / gesamt gesehen / im Gesamtbild / Gesamt London / als Ganzes betrachtet / in all seinen Facetten

Both your proposals would fit, I think.

> London ist insgesamt fantastisch.
>
> London ist im Ganzen fantastisch.

Ich würde gerne von Muttersprachlern wissen, ob meine Vorschläge richtig sind.

Comment: Native here: Well done!